# Send notification to email

Tags: php, laravel, wamp, laravel-mail

I work on a website project with the laravel framework and I want when I click on the button send a notification either send to the user's email

```
  $invite = Invite::create([
    'name' => $request->get('name'),
    'email' => $request->get('email'),
    'token' => str_random(60),
]);

$invite->notify(new UserInvite());
```

tnx to help me

Comment: Are you using laravel 5.4 ?

Comment: Everything you need is in https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are using is mail notification, Here is the answer but you can refer to notification section of laravel docs for more information:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/notifications

first generate the notification using your terminal in project folder:

php artisan make:notification UserInvite

Then in generated file specify your driver to be `'Mail'`. byr default it is. Also laravel has a nice sample code there. And it is better you inject your $invite to the notification so you can use it there. here is a quick sample code. You can find the notification generated under App\Notifications.

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use App\Invite;

class UserInvite extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
use Queueable;


/**
 * Create a new notification instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    //
}

public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['mail']; // Here you specify your driver, your case is Mail
}

public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->greeting('Your greeting comes here')
        ->line('The introduction to the notification.') //here is your lines in email
        ->action('Notification Action', url('/')) // here is your button
        ->line("You can use {$notifiable->token}"); // another line and you can add many lines
}
}
```

now you can call your notification:

```
$invite->notify(new UserInvite());
```

since you are notifying on invite, your notifiable is the same invite. As a result in your notification you can use `$notification->token` to retrieve the token of `invite object`.

Please let me know if I can be of any help.
regards.